# How to sort csv data based on date column in go

Tags: go

I am completely new to GO. Please, can anyone help with how to sort CSV ([][]string) data based on the date column?
Because there were duplicates in data I converted it to map to remove duplicates and back to slice. But by this step now data is unsorted.

How can I sort data based on the date column? 
Can anyone help, please?

REMOVE DUPLICATES

```
func removeDuplicatesFromListQuote(quotes [][]string) [][]string {
dict := make(map[string][]string)
for i, val := range quotes {
    if i == 0 {
        continue
    }
    dict[val[0]] = []string{val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4], val[5]}
}

var unique [][]string
newLine := make([]string, 0)
unique = append(unique, []string{"Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"})
for key, val := range dict {
    newLine = []string{key, val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4]}
    unique = append(unique, newLine)
}
```

e

DATA TO SORT

`Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
05111985,0.33,0.34,0.33,0.33,26885600
12021986,0.43,0.43,0.42,0.43,33264000
11051999,1.60,1.65,1.56,1.60,114648800
03052000,4.25,4.33,3.99,4.11,122449600
01112004,3.75,3.80,3.72,3.75,150512600
19072017,150.48,151.42,149.95,151.02,20923000
17091992,1.69,1.69,1.62,1.64,43108800
28051985,0.32,0.32,0.30,0.30,127741600
24071985,0.29,0.30,0.29,0.29,42179200
06042000,4.67,4.80,4.40,4.47,64906800
13042009,17.14,17.28,17.00,17.17,97309100
26022018,176.35,179.39,176.21,178.97,38162200
15051995,1.54,1.56,1.52,1.56,98338800
23031999,1.23,1.23,1.17,1.18,103888400
11092003,1.59,1.63,1.58,1.61,53421200
14072017,147.97,149.33,147.33,149.04,20132100
07031990,1.25,1.29,1.25,1.26,51055200
06061995,1.56,1.58,1.55,1.57,78817200`

Comment: Look at this package and its examples: https://golang.org/pkg/sort/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add add a few methods for sort.Sort to call and sort your data. It appears the first column of your data is a date formatted as MMDDYYYY.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "time"
)

type CSV [][]string

// Determine if one CSV line at index i comes before the line at index j.
func (data CSV) Less(i, j int) bool {
    dateColumnIndex := 0
    date1 := data[i][dateColumnIndex]
    date2 := data[j][dateColumnIndex]
    timeT1, _ := time.Parse("01022006", date1)
    timeT2, _ := time.Parse("01022006", date2)

    return timeT1.Before(timeT2)
}

// Other functions required for sort.Sort.
func (data CSV) Len() int {
    return len(data)
}
func (data CSV) Swap(i, j int) {
    data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i]
}

func main() {
    data := [][]string{
        []string{"05111985", "0.33", "0.34", "0.33"},
        []string{"11051999", "1.60", "1.65", "1.56"},
        []string{"12021986", "0.43", "0.43", "0.42"},
    }

    // Sort the data in place using the methods above.
    sort.Sort(CSV(data))
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Outputs: `[[05111985 0.33 0.34 0.33] [12021986 0.43 0.43 0.42] [11051999 1.60 1.65 1.56]]`.

Comment: Stephen, thank you very much, this is it exactly I was looking for. Thank you.